# Debugging JavaScript in Firefox Add-On

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am basically adding a panel to a widget using the Firefox Add-On SDK. I've placed my HTML file in the data directory along with my CSS and JavaScripts. The page doesn't work and I am trying to see if there are any errors. However, Firebug isn't installed so I can't seem to find where my JavaScript errors are occurring. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install firebug, you can try the basic error console (CTL+SHIFT+J by default).

If you want another plugin than firebug then you can use 'web developer' (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) which will give you a JS console among other things.

Comment: Also, if you are running the add-on from the command-line using `cfx run`, any console.log statements should appear in the shell you launched cfx from.

Comment: Firebug is fairly useless when debugging Firefox extensions, as is Web Developer.